# How do I tell wix to install a file in a directory set in a property?

Tags: wix

I want to do the following where XLSTART is defined as:

```
   <CustomAction Id="AssignXLSTART" Return="check" Execute="firstSequence" Directory ='XLSTART' Value='[AppDataFolder]\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART'>
    </CustomAction>
```

And then I have a subsequent CustomAction that calls some C# code that may change this value.

And then in the list of files to install I have:

```
  <Directory Id="XlStartFolderId" Name="[XLSTART]">
    <Component Id="ExcelMacro_xla" Guid="26D21093-B617-4fb8-A5E7-016493D46055" DiskId="1">
      <File Id="ExcelXLA" Name="AutoTagExcelMacro.xlam" ShortName="XLMacro.xla" Source="$(var.srcFolder)\AutoTagExcelMacro.xlam"/>
    </Component>
  </Directory>
```

But the above puts it in the INSTALLDIR[XLSTART]. How do I get it to read this as a property?

Comment: Do you need to target different versions of Office? I haven't worked on addins for a long, long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. You need to install to the INSTALLDIR and then use CopyFile

```
  <!-- place it in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\XLSTART\ -->
  <Component Id="ExcelMacro_xla" Guid="26D21093-B617-4fb8-A5E7-016493D46055" DiskId="1">
    <File Id="ExcelXLA" Name="AutoTagExcelMacro.xlam" ShortName="XLMacro.xla" Source="$(var.srcFolder)\AutoTagExcelMacro.xlam">
        <CopyFile Id='CopyXlMacro' DestinationProperty='XLPATH' DestinationName='AutoTagExcelMacro.xlam'/>
    </File>
  </Component>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to install to the userprofile directory you refer to like this:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="LocalAppDataFolder">

    <Directory Id="Microsoft" Name="Microsoft">
      <Directory Id="Excel" Name="Excel">
        <Directory Id="XLSTART" Name="XLSTART">

          <Component Id="ExcelAddIn" Feature="MyFeature" Guid="{11111-1111-GUID-HERE-YOURGUIDHERE}">
            <File Source="C:\SourceFiles\MyAddin.xla" />
            <RemoveFolder Id="Microsoft" On="uninstall" Directory="Microsoft" />
            <RemoveFolder Id="Excel" On="uninstall" Directory="Excel" />
            <RemoveFolder Id="XLSTART" On="uninstall" Directory="XLSTART" />
            <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\MySoftware" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes" />
          </Component>

      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
</Directory>
```

I would suggest you use the per-machine xlstart folder instead - if it still exists. I am not sure it does. The the addin is loaded for every user on the box on every launch. Generally I prefer this. It has been ages since I looked at this, so this could have changed in newer Office versions - in fact I am sure it has, but the details are unclear to me.

***System Folder Properties***: There are a number of **`System Folder Properties`** that can be used in MSI files to specify installation location - **`LocalAppDataFolder`** is just one of them: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/property-reference#system-folder-properties

Comment: I prefer the per machine. But that is in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\XLSTART\ and the C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16 I have in a property - but there's not a LocalAppDataFolder equivalent for the location of Office (it can be h:\office for example). So how can I place in that?

Comment: I guess you would need to read the location from the registry (that is a moving target based on version I would presume). The might be better ways to distribute addins - maybe based on active directory. I am not sure. [Deploy office addins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish). I assume you are making a "general-purpose" package for your own addins?

Comment: Right, I am able to get the location from the registry. I have that folder in a property. But how do I use that property as the directory to install to?

Comment: I unchecked this because I need to set from a property to do it as you suggested - install it in the folder where Excel was installed.